# Appropriate location for scheduled tasks

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

In Windows, where is the most appropriate place to store an executable that will be ran as a scheduled task on a server?

- A file share?
- "C:"?
- "C:\Windows"?
- Others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stay out of C: and C:\Windows.  Never put it on a file share (what if it isn't available)?
I'd just use a subdirectory of C:\Program Files (to be more precise, of %ProgramFiles% - the user's system may not be installed on C:, for instance).